# Plugin '*' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Tags: intellij-plugin

I am writing a small plugin for PhpStorm. During development, I run it in IDEA and everything works fine there. However, after I try to enable it in PhpStorm I get the following error:

```
Plugin 'name' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation [plugin compatibility](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-compatibility.html) says that if your plugin does not have module dependencies (built-in plugins that are non-removable parts of the IDE), then it is considered legacy and will load only in IDEA, as reported by the error message.

In order to fix this error, you need to explicitly add a dependency to one of the modules. For example, `com.intellij.modules.platform`:

Add the following line to `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>
```

And the plugin should load successfully in PhpStorm.